# Force browser to not use cache when requested for file using anchor tag

Tags: html, internet-explorer, anchor

I have an anchor tag that is used to request the download of a file.

Like this:

```
<a href="app/results?fileName=t12.txt&other-param=something" title="Click to download"> Download </a>
```

The file may be modified on the server very often, so I want to make sure the browser does not cache the file.

However, testers found out that, although it seems to always download the file when you click on the link, when you right-click on the link and choose "Save As...", the browser seems to choose to use the cached file instead. This was tested with IE9.

How can I force the browser (especially IE9) to always download the file in every case?

Comment: Can you add a random number in the query string? That should prevent the caching.

Comment: Ok, will try that... hadn't thought about it!!! Pretty sure you can add this as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Oh no... sorry actually this won't work unless you refresh the page.... I wanted to always be sure even if you don't refresh the page.

Comment: Well you could do something with a click handler to change the random number after each click... but I'm not sure how else you would do it without a page refresh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my own comment for one of the answers:

According to wikipedia I can set the response header parameter: Cache-Control: no-cache

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Effects_of_selected_HTTP_header_fields

After receiving a response with this header, the browser will not cache this data anymore.

Comment: The question suggests that one is looking for a client-side solution to the problem. In which case, setting a response header from the server is not an option. I think that JavaKungFu's answer is a better response to the question as asked.

Comment: There's no suggestion that the answer should be limited to client-side at all. In fact, the correct place to decide whether or not something is cache-able is on the server, not the client.

Answer (score 8):

I'll add as an answer. Try adding a random number to the query part of the href:

```
?param=[random]
```

Comment: You're right, I can probably change the query using JavaScript every time someone clicks on the link... but just thought the <a> tag would have something like no-cache=true

Comment: Not aware of a no-cache parameter on an <a> tag. I assume the server is already sending a no-cache header for this file?

Comment: That's the thing... the request header does not have no-cache.... I wanted to force it to have that.

Comment: Will the browser "no-cache" if I set the response header no-cache to t rue?

Comment: Ok, according to wikipedia I can set the response header parameter: **Cache-Control: no-cache** http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Effects_of_selected_HTTP_header_fields

Comment: No! Never add random parameter to avoid caching. If you are using cache proxies like Varnish then you are filling cache with useless entries that will never be used. You should make a use of Cache-Control and Pragma header parameters.