# Can get requests placed by <a> tags include data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know that requests placed by jQuery `$.get()` can include an optional parameter for additional data. I was wondering if there was any way to pass that information through requests that come about by clicking an  link, or relocation the windows location.

Comment: You can use query string parameters (e.g., http://example.com/page.html?param=value&another=different)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use a [Query String](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).

Excerpt:

> Typical URL containing a query string is as follows:
>
> http://example.com/over/there?name=ferret
>
> When a server receives a request for such a page, it may run a program, passing the query string, which in this case is, name=ferret unchanged, to the program. The question mark is used as a separator, and is not part of the query string.

So your anchor could be:

```
<a href="http://example.com/over/there?name=ferret">My Link</a>
```

or

```
<a href="//example.com/over/there?name=ferret">My Link</a>
```

or

```
<a href="/there?name=ferret">My Link</a>
```

Be aware that you can get [caching issues by links/get requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10274591/force-browser-to-not-use-cache-when-requested-for-file-using-anchor-tag).

Comment: Do I simply add the ?key=value to the end of the links href?

Comment: You can do that.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to pass data through a link as the page is visited is to use [URL Parameters/Query Strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).